# After MCU NVIC_GenerateSystemReset(), USB TX not working

Tags: c, usb, reset, stm32

I don't know why I can send text from PC to MCU through usb but I can't let MCU send text to PC after MCU reset.

I am using STM32F103C8. Bootloader start address is `0x8000000`, Firmware start address is `0x8004000`. Of course, NVIC table base address of Bootloader and Firmware are `0x8000000` and `0x8004000`, respectively.

In my firmware, PC recognized MCU using a virtual COM port, so I can tx/rx through usb VCOM port. 
After backing-up USB-related registers to backup registers, my Firmware resets MCU by using `NVIC_GenerateSystemReset()`.

----------FIRMWARE----------------

```
BKP_WriteBackupRegister(BKP_DR5, GetCNTR());
BKP_WriteBackupRegister(BKP_DR6, GetISTR());
BKP_WriteBackupRegister(BKP_DR7, GetDADDR());
BKP_WriteBackupRegister(BKP_DR8, GetBTABLE());
BKP_WriteBackupRegister(BKP_DR9, GetENDPOINT(0));
BKP_WriteBackupRegister(BKP_DR10, GetENDPOINT(1));
BKP_WriteBackupRegister(BKP_DR11, GetENDPOINT(2));
BKP_WriteBackupRegister(BKP_DR12, GetENDPOINT(3));
BKP_WriteBackupRegister(BKP_DR3, 10); // this is for indicating a jump from firmware.
NVIC_GenerateSystemReset();
```

-----------BOOTLOADER(pseudo code)--------------

```
if((BKP_ReadBackupRegister(BKP_DR3) == 10))
{

    // DO NOT CHANGE USB_DISCONNECT PIN which is for controlling the 
    // PULL-UP status of USBDP. 

    // (If I do this, USB virtual com port will be disconnected from PC. 
    // I don't want this to happen.
    // But I found that if I put this pin high and then put it low, 
    // tx/rx both work fine but VCOM port will be disconnected and then reconnected.)

    USB_Init();

    // SET CNTR, DADDR, BTABLE, 
    //     ENDPOINT0, ENDPOINT1, ENDPOINT2, ENDPOINT3 according to backup registers. 
}
```

After that, I found that the PC keeps the VCOM port that has been recognized while the Firmware ran(without reconnecting after entering the bootloader again), and I can send characters through this usb virtual com port to MCU.

But MCU cannot send characters to PC through usb.

```
extern void USB_TxDByte(u8 dat)
{
    Delay(1);
    UserToPMABufferCopy(&dat, ENDP1_TXADDR,1);
    SetEPTxCount(ENDP1, 1);
    SetEPTxValid(ENDP1);
}
```

The following are register values (during bootloader):

> EP0  EP1  EP2  EP3  CNTR  ISTR  FNR  DADDR  BTABLE
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A475 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A5B3 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A6F1 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 6030 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A16E 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A2AC 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 63EA 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 6529 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A667 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A7A5 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A0E3 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A221 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A360 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A49E 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A5DC 0087 0000
>
> 5210 0031 0622 3003 8600 0000 A71A 0087 0000

When I can do tx/rx correct in firmware, I found that only ISTR register is 0x0900, other values are the same (except FNR...). But ISTR register cannot be set, only reset is possible.

Comment: Can you check the usb transactions with a USB sniffer?